# Void function with an Error of non-void function does not return a value

Tags: c, compiler-errors, return-value, return-type, function-definition

Could anyone help me understand why this function produces an error of:

error: non-void function does not return a value
[-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 error generated.

```
void  *ft_clearpath(char **arr)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while(arr[i])
        free(arr[i++]);
    free(arr);
}
```

Clearly, it is a void function and should not have a return value. It supposes to clear the path before exiting my program.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It's not a "void function", it that returns `void *`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do not know how I missed this! hahaha. Fixed already.

Comment: Sounds like you got tripped by your own coding style. Maybe consider switching to a style like `void* ft_clearpath(char** arr)`.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of the function is the pointer type `void *`

```
void  *ft_clearpath(char **arr)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while(arr[i])
        free(arr[i++]);
    free(arr);
}
```

So the function should return a pointer but it returns nothing.

Either define it like

```
void  *ft_clearpath(char **arr)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while(arr[i])
        free(arr[i++]);
    free(arr);

    return NULL;
}
```

and call it for example like

```
arr = ft_clearpath( arr );
```

(instead of the name `arr` use the name of the pointer declared in the caller of the function)

or declare it like

```
void  ft_clearpath(char **arr)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while(arr[i])
        free(arr[i++]);
    free(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `void` type of pointer is a unique pointer type.
It allows us to point to any data type, from an integer value or a float to a string of characters. Hence, it is NOT a `void` function.

To make it one, remove the asterisk (`*`) from the function signature.